# Autofill field in access form by concatenating string values from other text fields

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010, string-concatenation, autofill

I am currently working on a form in an access 2010 database to enter some data. The form contains 3 text fields: field1, field2, and field3.

`field1` and `field2` will be filled out by the user and after that, `field3` should be automatically filled by *concatenating* the values of field1 and field2 with an *underscore*: `<field1>_<field2>`

I tried to enter this in various fields with the expression builder in the properties-table of `field3`, like in the events section or in the data section without success (something like  `=[Forms]![field1] & "_" & [Forms![field2]`  ). Also, VBA is not an option for me.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like, you are trying to UPDATE the concatenated values into the field of the table. This is called as performing a calculation or data dependency. You are not supposed to do this. This sort of calculation and concatenations should stay in Forms, Queries and reports and not in Tables. As these can be obtained when and where needed. More information on  why Calculated fields are not the best is explained here : http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html

Although if you want to display in the Form, then by all means just create a Control and set its Control Source as,

```
= [ControlName1] & "_" & [ControlName2]
```

Comment: Hey PaulFrancis, thank you for your quick reply! Maybe I should explain the background: field3 is a code for the user (they are biologists), they print it and stick it onto the probe, to identify this probe. In my form, they enter the data of this probe.